# How to create Sessions in salesforce? Does Salesforce allows to make Sessions?

Tags: apex, rest-api, session, website-integration

I want to integrate Salesforce with some website from which I want to get some data. According to that website API, we have to create Sessions and then other working.
I have searched for sessions in salesforce but have not found any related information that makes me clear about it. 
So please give me some right direction to get my answer. 
Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to connect from Salesforce to a 3rd party website and get some data which you'll then use somehow in Salesforce?  Is the website API something you can share a link to?  It sounds like you're needing to do an outbound connection, but there are many different ways to achieve that and it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions to SFDC can be established via below mechanisms

1)create a connected app in SFDC and do an oauth of external system with SFDC.Typically used if you are planning to use REST API of platform

2)use enterprise or partner WSDL and use login() call to get sessionId.

If you need details you will need to deep dive the documentation on this.

Comment: By using this method, Can I create session by using apex code? 
Because I have to create Session and handle it in coding. to get access to Website API

Answer (score 0):

When using the $Cache.Session global variable, fully qualify the key name with the namespace and partition name. This example is an output text component that retrieves a cached value from the namespace myNamespace, partition myPartition, and key key1.

1

Unlike with Apex methods, you can’t omit the myNamespace.myPartition prefix to reference the default partition in the org.

Use local instead of the namespace name to refer to the org’s namespace, whether or not a namespace is defined for the org.

1

If the cached value is a data structure that has properties or methods, like an Apex List or a custom class, those properties can be accessed in the $Cache.Session expression by using dot notation. For example, this markup invokes the List.size() Apex method if the value of numbersList is declared as a List.

1

This example accesses the value property on the myData cache value that is declared as a custom class.

1